# Filling left side of a float: right element in a full width design

Tags: html, css, css-float, autofill

I am working on a new design in HTML5/CSS3 and it has been a while since I last worked with html more than for writing content, not layout.

The thing I am trying to achieve is a "full-width" or rather "80% width" design so that it fits the browser size down to 800px. (min-width).

A part of the content will contain a navigation block placed to the right (fixed size, say 300px), I have achieved this by using float although I have learned to hate float because of the "clearfix" issue, bur for the lack of better.

To the left of it I wanted the content to take up space to the right floating element.

**However if that content grows beyond the width then it pushes the right floated element down.**

So something like:

```
   -----------------------------------------------------------
          |                 Header                    |
          |                <header>                   |
          |-------------------------------------------|
   <-10%->|         <- Fill ->            |<- 300px ->|<-10%->
          |                               |           |
          |         <section>             |  <aside>  |
   -----------------------------------------------------------
```

Section (id=articles) is set to:

```
margin: 0 0 0 30px;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
```

Aside (id=sidebar) is set to:

```
margin: 0 30px 10px 30px;
width: 290px;   

border:1px solid #6B6B6B;

border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;

box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px #6B6B6B inset;

display: inline-block;
float: right;
```

Ways of fixing it:

- **display: table and table-cell, works but it adds extra tags I would like to avoid, also not sure that works everywhere?**
- flexbox? well so I thought but having issues with it, but it is not widely supported anyways.
- Let all have fixed width.
- Let all have dynamic width. (ohh boy)
- Tables, but we know that discussion all to well.

**Now ill properly work on with the first one on that list as that is the only thing that currently let me achieve the goal, but I would like to see if there wasn't a more clean way.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? Create a container for the left and right pieces. Provide a right margin to make room for the right container. You could float it, but I absolutely positioned it because you hate floats =).

http://jsfiddle.net/Z62f2/

```
div { border: 1px solid gray; width: }
#container { width: 80%; min-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;  }
#header { height: 100px; }
#content { position: relative; }
#left { margin-right: 300px; height: 1000px; }
#right { width: 300px; height: 500px; position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; }

<div id="container">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="left">Left</div>
        <div id="right">Right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well it's the small part where "floats" does not expand their container, or can't by a CSS tag be made to, I find that lacking, it would be ok if you could instruct them to either expand their parrent or not (or on the parrent level ask it to expand to it's floated children or not)... But having to use an extra invisible div to reset the float is just... well...

Your solution doesn't save me from the need of that extra "content" container which is really what I wanted, so is there any arguments to using it over "display: table" ?

Comment: (Extra comment due to space)

This would be somewhat what I have now, except that my actual page uses "aside", "section" and "header" tags instead of divs: http://jsfiddle.net/Z62f2/6/

Comment: Using display table-cell is perfectly reasonable. Not supported by IE7, but I don't support that anyways. What you seem to want isn't possible and that is because of the way the css rules are written. There is no concept of, I want you to be as big as possible, except for this much. I certainly see this request a lot though. That being said, two extra tags or a clearing div is really minimal additional markup to get what you want. I wouldn't spend any time worrying about that.

Comment: Ok, ill stick with what I have then. And sure an extra container might be a minimal addition, but if I could get rid of it then why not?... After all one extra container becomes to, then three if one does not watch out, so it was merely an attempt to make it as clear as possible, and I thought it was possible to do it. And I don't care that much about IE7 support anymore, this is not a huge international site, this is a personal blog with some portfolio, galleries and other stuff added aimed mostly at IT so readers who would be interested are very likely to have an updated browser anyways.

Comment: Although from a technical standpoint I should care when I am in that field, but in the long run I might add a special handler for such cases, handing a different style-sheet to older browsers (I should be able to handle that in my CSS route handler/http handler) and just make it a static with design in that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to take a stab at this,

Here's how I would mark it up within the HTML you already have. Basically I inserted another div to contain the section and the aside.

```
<div id="contentContain">
    <div id="section"></div>
    <div id="aside"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS..

```
#contentContain {width: 80%; }
#section {float:left; width: 60%;}
#aside {float:left; width: 40%; }
```

This code should give you some more perspective, and It works, you can have "more" content in aside and it won't break the layout.

Best of luck!

Comment: I didn't wan't aside to be a percentage, but a fixed with, having a "contentContainer" is what I have atm. to wrap those and then use "display: table" on the container and then "display: table-cell" on the aside and section (well their ID's respectively) but I wanted to avoid that extra html tag if I could.